# Confusion about base change matrix notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If we want to get a matrix that changes the vectors from basis $B_1$ to basis $B_2$, we call that matrix $P_{B_1B_2}$ and it't entries are the coefficients of vectors in $B_1$ being written these coefficients from basis $B_2$.

For example:

[image]

This basis $B$ to standard base. The transitional matrix would be $$P_{BS} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0 &-1 & 1\\ 0&0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

However, the solution to this problem is written in the reverse order in subscript, so that this is the matrix $P_{SB}$, however, what is the correct notation, if we want to write "transitional matrix from $B$ to standard basis", so that we take base vectors from $B$ and write them with base vectors of $S$(... the standard basis) and then put the coeffficients into columns and get the transitional matrix.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking how to compute $P_{BS}$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am asking if the notation is correct for $P_{BS}$

Comment: @BenGrossmann or should it be the other way around, so : $P_{SB}$

Comment: There is no universal notation here, unfortunately. It could be that the solutions you found use the opposite convention from the one you're used to

Comment: @BenGrossmann Looks like that will be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BenGrossmann stated, question is based on agreement at a certain math community, how they write the subscript for the basis change.